# How can I disable PIM and keyfile prompts when using VeraCrypt through command line?

Tags: macos, veracrypt

```
veracrypt --text --mount --protect-hidden=no /Users/admin/test /Volumes/test
Enter password for /Users/admin/test:
Enter PIM for /Users/admin/test:
Enter keyfile [none]:
```

I would like to only have to enter password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`veracrypt --text --help --verbose`

**Note:** on macOS, the binary is located at `/Applications/VeraCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/VeraCrypt`. Run the following to create a `veracrypt` symlink.

```
ln -s /Applications/VeraCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/VeraCrypt /usr/local/bin/veracrypt

# Make sure `/usr/local/bin` is added to the `PATH` environment variable by adding `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/sbin` to `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` and reloading the terminal.
```

## PIM

```
--pim=PIM
 Use specified PIM to mount/open a volume. Note that passing a PIM on the 
 command line is potentially insecure as the PIM may be visible in the process 
 list (see ps(1)) and/or stored in a command history file or system logs.
```

Shout-out to Michael for `--pim=0`. The `0` option is not mentioned in the docs.

## keyfile

```
-k, --keyfiles=KEYFILE1[,KEYFILE2,KEYFILE3,...]
 Use specified keyfiles when mounting a volume or when changing password
 and/or keyfiles. When a directory is specified, all files inside it will be
 used (non-recursively). Multiple keyfiles must be separated by comma.
 Use double comma (,,) to specify a comma contained in keyfile's name.
 Keyfile stored on a security token must be specified as
 token://slot/SLOT_NUMBER/file/FILENAME. An empty keyfile (-k "") disables
 interactive requests for keyfiles. See also options --import-token-keyfiles,
 --list-token-keyfiles, --new-keyfiles, --protection-keyfiles.
```

## Mount volume with password prompt only

```
veracrypt --text --keyfiles="" --mount --pim=0 --protect-hidden=no /Users/admin/test /Volumes/test
```

## Dismount volume

```
veracrypt --text --dismount /Users/admin/test
```

Answer (score 3):

To disable the PIM prompt:  [--pim=0](https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/technical/thread/d17ff023/)

I can't find any no key option anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Michael! Your tip isn’t in the docs. Check my answer for keyfile.